# PlayStation says I already have Playstation Plus but Overwatch says i don't

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I have my own PSN account which was created on my mom's PS4 (not a sub account I’m over 18) and so I recently bought my own PS4. Without PlayStation plus from my mom I went to go purchase a subscription and it says I already own it. Or when I try to buy it’s just gonna add to my mom's subscription.

I tried to get into a game (*Overwatch* to be exact) and it says I need to buy plus. Both my mom and I are clueless.

Comment: Was the account ever a sub-account? Sub-accounts AFAIK don't get automatically uncoupled when you reach 18 years of age. I'd make sure your account is actually uncoupled from your mom's first.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of PlayStation's wacky permissions things:

1. Because you are a sub-account to your mom, you have limitations to what you can purchase. PlayStation Plus is apparently one of those limitations. It might also be more than your mom let's the account spend per month. It might be that it's more money than your mom has on her account. There are a bunch of reason why a sub can't buy.
2. Even though you are still covered by your mom's PlayStation Plus account as a sub, she can only have one "primary" PS4 console. So while you're playing on her console, everything should work fine, but on your new console, she does not (or at least I'm assuming she does not) have an account on it. She would need to log in you your console and declare it her primary PS4. But that means the original would no longer allow her to access PS+ content.

You're only real option is to go through the process of [detaching yourself from her account](https://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2017/02/02/psls-help-desk-how-to-upgrade-psn-sub-account-to-master-account/#/slide/1) and paying for PS+ yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Even once detached from your mom’s account, you can both still mutually enjoy both account content and Plus subscription simultaneously. (Won’t work if a third PS4 comes into the ring.—Siblings?)

Let your mom’s account be primary on your console, and your account primary on your mom’s console (only necessary if your mom wants to play your games or use your subscription or other content). Both of you keep using only their own account, but not set to primary. You can have up to 16 accounts on a PS4, all could be primary or not, but an account can only be primary on one console at a time.

On each PS4 you can use all subscriptions/games/content of the currently used logged-in account (primary or not) and of all further primary accounts.